# Capturing table changes with CDC and In Memory tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, change-data-capture

We had a plan to capture table changes with CDC until we realized that it doesn't support In Memory tables.

Is there another way (preferably as straightforward as CDC) to capture data changes (from in memory tables) in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: No, not as far as I know outside of roll your own.

Comment: Yes. System-Versioned Temporal Tables with Memory-Optimized Tables. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt590207.aspx